# Manipulate the Performance Monitor Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter, perfmon

Is it possible to programmatically add existing performance counters to the performance monitor (perfmon.exe) and display them as a report view? if so, how can it be done in C#?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx) helps. Otherwise there is a [native API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373088.aspx), which might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks dowhilefor for the comment. I've gone through the first link, what I want is to automate the last part of it, "Making performance visible", the part where you manually add the counters to the monitor. I want to invoke the performance monitor with the counters I need to be displayed already added to it instead of the CPU counter that is loaded by default.

Comment: Not possible, Perfmon.exe doesn't have a programmable automation interface.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I thought of writing a config file and running logman on it. At least it will have some steps automated.

http://geekswithblogs.net/RobBowman/archive/2009/07/08/scripting-perfmon.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Import the PLA library by browsing the file in your .net Project (%windir%\System32\PLA.dll (Vista or later))

check reference here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372631(v=vs.85).aspx